# Issues with Bootstrap after using jquery.removeClass

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm encountering following problem with the twitter bootstrap framework and jQuery:
I have the following form (simplified, the real form is built with cakephp's formhelper and has a lot more classes and ids):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name">
      <span class="help-block">Supporting help text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">Description</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="description">
      <span class="help-block">Supporting help text</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

After server-side validation, i add the `.error` class to the respective control-group.

now for example the validation for name is ok, but it fails for description, the description control-group gets the error class and is displayed correctly (red, standard bootstrap). but the name input field is red, too. i checked the source code and the name's control-group has no `.error` class.
what confuses me, is, that only the input field is display with the red border, the appropriate label tag is displayed correctly (default color).

Here's a screenshot for clearer understanding.

[image: my_problem]

Check it in Chrome and Firefox, so i can exclude a browser bug. I also added and removed the class manually in chromes developer tool thing and it worked as intended. why is that? does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form` was inside another `div` with `.control-group`-class (not shown here) and the `error`-class was applied using jQuerys [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) searching for `.control-group` which goes all the way up the DOM tree and caused `.error` to be applied to the `div` which contained both input fields.

Removing the enclosing `div`s class solved the problem. This is a bit unfair as I had access to the complete code. :(